# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Tags: android, file, serialization, android-sharing

I'm trying to **create text file** and **share** it (by Bluetooth, email..)

```
File file = null;
try {
    file = createFile2(json);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
shareIntent.setType(getString(R.string.share_contact_type_intent));
```

Here is the createFile2() fun:

```
 public File createFile2(String text) throws IOException {
        File file = new
                File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.txt");

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bufferedWriter.write(text);
        bufferedWriter.close();
        return file;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
Bundle﹕ Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.io.File.  The default value <null> was returned.
Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
            at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1212)
            at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4652)
            at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7235)
            at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7219)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
```

Comment: putExtra is not defined for File the the [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 9):

When filling the `EXTRA_STREAM` for an `ACTION_SEND` intent you must provide the `Uri` for the resource, not the `File` object itself.

As for the exception: while in general you *can* put a `File` object as part of the extended data of an `Intent` (since it implements `Serializable`), the receiver expects a `Parcelable` instance for `EXTRA_STREAM`, which `File` isn't.

Comment: I think you mean `android.net.Uri`, which is a `Parcelable` and not `java.net.URI`

Comment: @dmcontador Yes, of course. But I was just referring to URI as a concept, not the specific class. :)